# C++ move semantics compilation error C2751

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++11, compiler-errors

I did some experiments with C++11 move semantics in MSVS2010 and found a compilation error I couldn't explain. Here is the code reproducing this error:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct NonCopyable
{
protected:
   NonCopyable() {}
private:
   NonCopyable( const NonCopyable& );
   NonCopyable& operator = ( const NonCopyable& );
};

struct A: private NonCopyable
{
   template< typename T >
   static std::unique_ptr< A > Create()
   {
      std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
      T t = T();
      return std::unique_ptr< A >( new A() );
   }
};

struct B: private NonCopyable
{
   B( std::unique_ptr< A >&& )
   {
      std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
   }
};

struct C: private NonCopyable
{
   C( B&& )
   {
      std::cout << __FUNCTION__<< std::endl;
   }
};

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
   C c( B( A::Create< char >() ) );
   return 0;
}
```

Trying to compile the code I receive following error message:

```
error C2751: 'A::Create' : the name of a function parameter cannot be qualified
```

But the error disappears if I change the main function like this:

```
int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
   // I've added extra parentheses around B( A::Create< char >() )
   C c( ( B( A::Create< char >() ) ) );
   return 0;
}
```

Could you explain me what's going on? Why do I need additional parentheses?

Comment: You ran afoul of a simple rule: Everything which can be a function declaration, is one.

Comment: @Deduplicator: That's still not clear to me. How does the compiler find a function declaration in string C c(B(A::Create<char>()))?

Comment: [Most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)

Comment: Hmm, MSVC clearly thinks this is a case of the most vexing parse, but both clang and gcc [compile your original example successfully](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ed2cbd40eb8a5281), so maybe this is an MSVC bug. And looking at it closer, I'm having a hard time coming up how this is MVP. `A::Create<char>` is not a type, so `A::Create<char>()` cannot decay to `A::Create<char>(*)()`

Comment: @Praetorian: Thanks for a helpful link. I've made some changes to main function:
typedef std::unique_ptr< A > (*Ptr)();
Ptr ptr = &A::Create< char >;
C c( B( ptr() ) );
And now I'm getting this warning:
warning C4930: 'C c(B (__cdecl *)(void))': prototyped function not called (was a variable definition intended?)

Comment: That's definitely MVP. You have a function named `c` that returns a `C` and takes a pointer to a function that returns `B` and takes a pointer to a function that returns `ptr` (aka `std::unique_ptr<A>(*)()`) and takes no arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the case of MVP ([Most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse))

Let's rewrite the main function to bring more clarity:

```
int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
   typedef std::unique_ptr< A > (*Ptr)();
   Ptr ptr = &A::Create< char >;
   C c( B( ptr() ) );
   return 0;
}
```

When the compiler will output verbose warning message:

```
warning C4930: 'C c(B (__cdecl *)(void))': prototyped function not called (was a variable definition intended?)
```

The compiler considers B( ptr() ) as a normal function declaration just like this:

```
int ( foo() )
{
   return 1;
}
```

That's why using extra parentheses helps to avoid compilation error.